# Windows Phone 7 - How to download a file with progress?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How would I download a large file in Windows Phone 7 with a progress bar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Claus's answer would work, a potentially easier solution would be to use a web client. It would look something like this:

```
    ...
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();
    wb.DownloadProgressChanged += wbchange;
    ...

    private void wbchange(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar2.Value = e.BytesReceived;
        progressBar2.Maximum = e.TotalBytesToReceive;

        int val = (int)(e.BytesReceived / 1048576);
        int max = (int)(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1048576);

        textBlock4.Text = val + "MB out of " + max.ToString() + "MB";
    }
```

This code would show a progress bar with the progress and a text block with the progress in MB.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't think Web Client could do it.

Comment: @msbg, If the downloadable file is a Text File, then the TotalBytesToReceive value is -1, how to get the orginal bytes please.

Answer (score 2):

See Microsofts [How to: Implement Background File Transfers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)